# pulling branch that doesn't have a folder from master

Tags: git

I entered a new project and I cloned the repository locally. Now I see what is in the master branch on that repository. So, I did

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Now I am in the new_branch. Everything is great, but I want to pull something from other branch, so I do

```
git pull origin other_branch
```

The thing is that "other_branch" doesn't have a folder which "master" branch has, but locally I didn't loose it by pulling. I don't want that folder locally because I only want communication with "other_branch", and not "master". How to solve that issue?

Comment: So, if I understand it correctlly, you're trying to pull changes to some branch and take a look at them? If so, then you should save your changes to your new_branch, then checkout to other_branch and pull changes. After you take a look at the changes, you can go ahead and checkout to new_branch again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What does `git status` say about the additional folder?

**EDIT 1**

Since I do not know more about your situation. You could try to remove the whole repo first (I know not the git way , but without a proper git status output I am unable to resolve all the posibilites in my head) and then directly clone the repo with the proper branch `git clone -b other_branch <url>` see [git help](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for more info

Comment: up to date...it just doesn't recognize him...when I did git pull, I got nano terminal for merging, but I don't know what to click. When I do ctrl+X, then it just changes other thing, but that folder is still there. It didn't delete it...

Comment: Questions for clarification like this should be comments and not answers. If you can't post a comment yet, then please restrict yourself to other interactions (like actual answers or questions) until you can.

Comment: @JoachimSauer sorry for that but I cannot comment yet since I have not enough rep yet. Please remove the downvote

Comment: @Alem Since I do not know more about  your situation. You could try to remove the whole repo first (I know not the git way , but without a proper git status output I am unable to resolve all the posibilites in my head)  and then directly clone the repo with the proper branch `git clone -b other_branch <url>` see [git help](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for more info

Comment: @MiEbe  Please, just copy paste that as an answer so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it did. That is the reason why I am saying that you copy paste that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Alem I copied it already, I guess you can accept